# Distinct maintenance page from report

Tags: magento-1.9, reports, maintenance

When I push my website in maintenance (with maintenance.flag), that send a 503.

When the website has a report, that send a 503 (*/src/errors/processor.php, function processReport()*).

I want to make a distinction between both.

In processReport(), can I change

> $this->_sendHeaders(503);

by

> $this->_sendHeaders(500);

or there is any contraindication ?

Maybe someone have a better idea ?